# How do I create a new genesis block for an altcoin?

Tags: altcoin, genesis-block

I'm trying to clone the Blackcoin sourcecode just for the hell of it but I can't seem to generate a genesis block. I can do it on normal coins, but not here. The Blackcoin developers seem to have shifted a lot of code into weird places.

For example, all of the coins major parameters are in [chainparams.cpp](https://github.com/rat4/blackcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp). However, there is no code in the link above or in [main.cpp](https://github.com/rat4/blackcoin/blob/master/src/main.cpp) to create a genesis block.

How do I make a genesis block for this coin?

Comment: I'd love to know myself but without being versed in C++ it's very difficult I gather. The other issue is the information is not shared openly in my experience. Why? Because of the influx of scams (Altcoin clones were released at the rate of 4-5 daily in July 2014; many were outright scams, including DafuqCoin, which was a Trojan, USBcoin, and Cachecoin, which just saw the developers charged) then there's the algorithms; Keep in mind Blackcoin is proof of stake and IIRC doesn't use sha256. I wish I could add more.

Comment: I am stuck here too. Have you find solution? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

They just removed the gen-generation part from the sources as it's not needed after the genesis being generated and already implemented (hardcoded) into the sources.

Comment: Hi. Then where is working code for newest source?