# How to mine a genesis block?

Tags: litecoin, genesis-block, mining-software

Following [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=225690.0) guide, I'm trying to learn how to mine a genesis block, not to launch another altcoin or anything, blockchain databases are going to be important and I want to be ahead of the curve.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/lhartikk/GenesisH0) script and working with the litecoin source. I have only changed the following:

```
find LoadBlockIndex() function, inside, change:
    - paraphrase (pszTimestamp) to any recent news phase.
    - get the latest unix time (do a google), and put in block.nTime.
    - set any nNonce (doesn't really matter)
you can change the time/nonce for testnet too, if you want to use it.
```

Those variables are now found in `chainparams.cpp` and I didn't change the testnet time/nonce.

After compiling when I try to run `litecoind` I get the following error:

```
litecoind: chainparams.cpp:220: CTestNetParams::CTestNetParams(): Assertion `hashGenesisBlock == uint256("0xf5ae71e26c74beacc88382716aced69cddf3dffff24f384e1808905e0188f68f")' failed.
Aborted
```

If anyone can help or point me in the direction of some modern documentation I'd me most grateful :)

Comment: If you change the genesis block you have to change the hash check assertion, because the hash will have changed.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/34107/how-do-i-create-a-new-genesis-block-for-an-altcoin. This question seems to have better answers, so maybe the linked question should be marked as a duplicate of this.

Comment: Thanks @StephenM347 but how do I calculate what the 'hash check assertion' should be?

Comment: Also there are no answers in the link you provided.

Comment: After this, you maybe suffer ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(, have  you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to make an altcoin](http://dillingers.com/blog/2015/04/18/how-to-make-an-altcoin/) on Bear's Den

Answer (score 0):

You have to add smth like this
genesis.nNonce   = 353314;
hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();

LogPrintf("Display genesis hash so we can input it below %s\n", hashGenesisBlock.ToString().c_str());

assert(hashGenesisBlock == uint256("0xe133d1d3f584f1c3f561e7d0606fa87dabb869325a979c2a82e2f3943c0e3370"));
vFixedSeeds.clear();

then after ./coind  in debug.log you can get genesis hash